# $\operatorname{range}T\cap\operatorname{range}U = \{0\}$ implies that $\{U,V\}$ is linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, linear-transformations

I am required to prove the following Claim. Is my argument valid.

> **Theorem**. If $V$ and $W$ are vector spaces and $T$ and $U$ are non-zero Linear transformations from $V$ to $W$ such that
>   $\operatorname{range}T\cap\operatorname{range}U = \{0\}$. then the set
>   $\{U,V\}$ is linearly independent in $\mathcal{L}(V,W)$.

**Proof.** Assume on the contrary that the set $\{U,V\}$ is linearly dependent that is for some $c\in\mathbf{F}$ either $T = cU$ or $U = cT$. Let us first consider the former case.

Since $T$ and $U$ are non-zero linear maps it follows that $c\neq 0$ and that for some non-zero vector $v\in V$ we have $Tv = U(cv)\neq 0$ evidently $Tv\in\operatorname{range}T$ and since $Tv = U(cv)$ it follows that $Tv\in\operatorname{range}U$ consequently $Tv\in\operatorname{range}T\cap\operatorname{range}U$ and so $Tv = 0$ resulting in a contradiction.

We may arrive at a similar absurdity when addressing the case $U = cT$.

$\blacksquare$

Comment: The theorem does not make sense. What does it mean for a linear transformation ($U$) and a vector space ($V$) to be linearly independent?

Comment: @angryavian It means that if $c_1T+c_2U$ is the zero transform then $c_1 = c_2 = 0$.

Comment: Then you are talking about $\{T, U\}$ and not $\{U,V\}$ as you wrote.

Comment: This confusion could have been avoided if you didn't use capital letters from the end of the alphabet to denote two different things. If $\;V,\,W\;$ are subspaces, what's the problem with denoting $\;f,g\;$ linear maps? Mathematics is hard enough as it is. Let us not make it harder with clumsy notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof is good.

You could simplify it by observing that from $T=cU$, you have $T(v)=U(cv)$, for every $v\in V$. Thus $T(v)\in\operatorname{range}T\cap\operatorname{range}U$, forcing $T(v)=0$, for every $v\in V$, which is a contradiction to $T\ne0$.